# Can a Chrome extension know what wifi access point name is being used?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to see if there's Chrome extension code that can identify what the currently connected wifi access point name is, and make a decision based on that. Is that currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest thing would be the network status web api.